# Meta Descritpion in HAML with outside variable

Tags: html, ruby, templates, haml, middleman

I'm trying to get my meta description to work in HAML and everything I try produces errors.

```
%meta{:name => "description", :content => "Some content"}/
%title 
  = data.page.title
```

The code above works. Now I try the following:

```
 %meta{:name => "description", :content => 
   = data.page.desc
   }/
 %title 
   = data.page.title
```

And I get unbalanced brackets error on the first line. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just for information here unbalanced brackets error is created because HAML only allow line breaks directly after a comma

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In HAML, the hash that you use to specify the attributes for an element can contain valid Ruby code, so you don't need to use `=` to evaluate a Ruby expression. Therefore, the code you're looking for is simply:

```
%meta{:name => "description", :content => data.page.desc}
```

Note that you don't need to append a `/` to the end of the `%meta` element declaration, as HAML will automatically treat it as a self-closing tag, like `img` or `br`.